# Django Runserver ImportError: No module named models

Tags: python, django, django-models, app-config

When I run Django App I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f8449a387d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/soho-website/backend/project/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url(r'', include('web.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/soho-website/backend/web/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from web import views, models
  File "/root/soho-website/backend/web/views.py", line 19, in <module>
    from captcha.models import CaptchaStore
ImportError: No module named models
```

But, If I comment the following line in my urls.py file: `url(r'', include('web.urls')),` where I define my Index Page, my App Works.

I have correctly installed all my Apps via Pip (Captcha, Ckeditor, MySQL, etc)

**Details:**

- My project name: **project**
- Django version: **1.9.5**
- Python version: **2.7.6 [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2**

**urls.py File**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    # Website URLs
    url(r'', include('web.urls')),

    # Admin URLs
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

base.py file (some config):

```
import os
from django.core.urlresolvers import set_urlconf

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

DOMAIN_URL = "http://MY_IP"
```

The structure of my application is:

[image]

What is wrong with my config?

### UPDATE

I have correctly installed Captcha with PIP INSTALL. In my Installed_APPS I defined captcha and if I add the follow line: `url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),` in my urls.py file the error persist.

This is my web/views.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python imports
import datetime
import json

# Django imports
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import View, ListView, DetailView, YearArchiveView, \
    MonthArchiveView, TemplateView, FormView
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.db.models import Q
from django.conf import settings


# Captcha imports
from captcha.models import CaptchaStore # This is the line where error occurs
from captcha.helpers import captcha_image_url

# APP imports.
from web.models import Slider, Woman, Article, CategoryArticle, CategoryWoman, \
    CategoryBlog, Blog, Banner
from web.constans import MONTHS
from web.utils import women_dates_list
from web.forms import ContactForm, RegisterForm, ContactModelForm
```

Sorry for my english.

### UPDATE 2

Error with Django-Ckeditor

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fe211911140>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/soho-website/backend/project/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    url(r'', include('web.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/soho-website/backend/web/urls.py", line 83, in <module>
    (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named urls
```

And this is my web/urls.py

```
# Django imports
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

# App imports
from web import views, models


# URLs
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  ##
  ## URLS of the Website
  ##
  # CAPTCHA
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),

  # CKEDITOR
    (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you installed not the captcha that you need. `pip install captcha` install [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/captcha). And it has no models. It seems that you need [django-simple-captcha](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-captcha). Install it by runing `pip install django-simple-captcha`.

**UPDATE**

Change `(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),` to `(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),`

Comment: I have captcha installed with pip.

Comment: Ok. The Captcha error disappeared but.. An error appeared in Ckeditor (App `django-ckeditor`): `No module named urls`. In my server I'm not using `virtualenv`. Is that error occurs in the version of django or python I have ? Sorry for this, I am a beginner in python- django .

Comment: Show me the full stack trace.